# laravel insert query value empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<elenco_clienti>
 <cliente>
  <cod>00001</cod>
  <name>xxxxxxxxxx</name>
  <address>VIA nnnnnnnn</address>
</cliente>
<cliente>
 <cod>00003</cod>
 <name>yyyyyyyyyyy</name>
 <address>VIA calllll</address>
</cliente>
<cliente>
 <cod>00005</cod>
 <name>oooooooooooo</name>
 <address></address>
</cliente>
</elenco_clienti>
```

I have this Xml file and make my array like this:

```
 $xml1 = simplexml_load_file($path);
 $json = json_encode($xml1);
 array = json_decode($json, true);
 $clien =$array['cliente'];
```

but when i put my query

```
 if(!empty($clien))
 {
     DB::table('clientis')->insert($clien);
     dd('Insert Recorded successfully.');
 }
```

I have the error

```
QueryException Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `clientis`......
```

i think for the value empty.....
what i do?
thanks

Comment: Are you certain `$clien` is an array? What happens if you change the `if` statement to `if(!empty($clien) && is_array($clien))`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `address` in the last item is an empty array:

```
2 => array:3 [▼
    "cod" => "00005"
    "name" => "oooooooooooo"
    "address" => []
]
```

You need to do something like this to fix this:

```
$clien = array_map(function($i) {
    $i['address'] = empty($i['address']) ? '' : $i['address'];
    return $i;
}, $clien);
```

Comment: but i need to fix other empty value in other place, not just this one. My array have to many value empty

Comment: @NuCarvignulu I gave you a solution for fixing all empty addresses.

Comment: but the empty value is not only in the address @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @NuCarvignulu just add the same code for any other column inside the `array_map()` closure.